# Regarding the bug message when installing Ubuntu 20.04.6

Tags: cpu

```
Physical machine configuration:
cpu:i7-6700k
Motherboard: Gigabyte B150M-VP
Motherboard bios version: F1
Memory: Kingston 16G 2133hz
Storage: Kingston SSD512G
```

When I used a USB flash drive to install Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on this machine, the following error message appeared.
what do I do
[image]

Comment: It may help if you're specific as to what you installed; you mention partial details (ie. Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS), but not if you're trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Server (using the `subiquity` installer), or Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Desktop (using the `ubiquity` installer). My guess from the picture you provided is it's a Server ISO using `subiquity` installer - but it's better if you just tell us & don't make us guess.  You're using an old release; have you tried a newer release?